# Multiply filtering in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, filtering

I have table with records in HTML and many filtering options by properties. User can choose none, one or more. I'm using mongoDb database and MongoDb driver in C#. How I can realize this filtering?

**Filter**

```
public class ConsultantFiltersModel
{
    public string RecruiterName { get; set; }
    public int? RecruiterCode { get; set; }
    public bool? WithouRecruiter { get; set; }
    public string FutureWorkerName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I pass this filter from client side, some properties are `Nullable`. I need to filter records by only non-null properties.

**I've tried to realize it like this**

```
public Consultant FilterRecords(ConsultantFiltersModel consultantFiltersModel)
{        
    return consultantsCollection
        .AsQueryable()
        .Where(recruiterNameFilter =>
         string.IsNullOrEmpty(consultantFiltersModel.RecruiterName) 
         ? true 
         : recruiterNameFilter.Recruiter.Value == consultantFiltersModel.RecruiterName)

         .Where(recruiterCodeFilter => 
         consultantFiltersModel.RecruiterCode.HasValue 
         ? true 
         : recruiterCodeFilter.Recruiter.Key == consultantFiltersModel.RecruiterCode)

         .Where(phoneNumberFilter => 
         string.IsNullOrEmpty(consultantFiltersModel.PhoneNumber)
         ? true 
         : phoneNumberFilter.FutureWorker.Phone.Contains(consultantFiltersModel.PhoneNumber))

         .Where(futureWorkerNameFilter =>
         string.IsNullOrEmpty(consultantFiltersModel.FutureWorkerName) 
         ? true 
         : futureWorkerNameFilter.FutureWorker.Name.Contains(consultantFiltersModel.FutureWorkerName))

        .FirstOrDefault();            
}
```

But I get this exception

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Non-static method requires a target.

Maybe it's not supported by mongoDbDriver? Any advises?

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck using the native mongodb Find() either using Lambda directly, or using the Builders to create your filters. They might be easier to build dynamically than the query above

```
var builder = Builders<YourObject>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq(x => x.YourField, "SomeValue");
var andFilter = builder.And(filter, builder.Eq(x => .SomeOtherField, "SomeOtherValue"));
var results = consultantsCollection.Find(andFilter).FirstOrDefault();
```

The Builders have a number of extensions methods for your filtering, as shown above, i am using .Eq() and .And(), but explore it and you will find an ectensive list to help you